passing an argument that is a string with double quotes inside a single quote
I get a quote error like this when passing an argument that is a string with double quotes inside a single quote. Can anyone help me see how to fix it?

function renderHTML(courseRender) {
    const render = courseRender.map(function (course) {
        return (
            `
                <li class='course-item-${course.id}'>
                <b>${course.name}</b>
                <button onclick="handleDeleteCours(${course.id})" class='btn-del'>Delete</button>
                <button onclick="innitValueInForm('${course.name}', '${course.description}', '${course.id}')" class="btn-    edit">Update</button> 
                <p>${course.description}</p>
                </li>
        
        `
    )
})
    ulElement.innerHTML = render.join('')
}

function innitValueInForm(nameValue, desValue, id){
    const btn_creat = document.querySelector('.btn-creat')
    btn_creat.className = 'btn-update'
    btn_creat.innerHTML = 'Update'

    document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value = nameValue
    document.querySelector('input[name="description"]').value = desValue

    btn_creat.onclick = function(){
        const dataUpdate = {
            name: document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value,
            description: document.querySelector('input[name="description"]').value
        }
    }
}

And here are my changes
<button onclick="innitValueInForm(\`${course.name}\`, \`${course.description}\`, '${course.id}')" class="btn-edit">Update</button>

<button onclick="innitValueInForm('${course.name.replace(/'/g, "\\'")}', '${course.description.replace(/'/g, "\\'")}', '${course.id}')" class="btn-edit">Update</button>


Can you please identify which line in the code sample is line 95 in your code?

You can save a set of quotes if you use data-attributes and move the event handler to a script instead of inline
